# Are an increasing number of gender transitioned people seeking to detransition?

Tags: gender

In a recent [essay](https://www.jkrowling.com/opinions/j-k-rowling-writes-about-her-reasons-for-speaking-out-on-sex-and-gender-issues/) defending her views on sex and gender issues, author J.K. Rowling writes:

> I’m concerned about the huge explosion in young women wishing to transition and also about the increasing numbers who seem to be detransitioning

Are increasing numbers of transitioned people seeking to detransition?

Comment: To my knowledge, there are few studies on that subject. The few that do exist suggest that detransitioners do exist, but are rather rare, see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6212091/. There are no actual scientific numbers on wether the total count is increasing, though considering the recent upwards trend in diagnosed gender dysphoria and subsequent treatment, it seems rather likely that at least the *absolute* (not necessarily the relative) number increased within the last decade.

Comment: Even if this were true, it most probably would be explained by the increasing number of people transitioning. I wouldn't read much into J.K. Rowling: she's been trying to backpedal from a bunch of misinformed takes for a while now.

Comment: @DonThousand doesn't seem like she's been backpedalling, more like sticking by her guns, and defending her opinions